# Nokogiri split nested elements that has same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm scraping a blog which has `post` and `comments`. `Comments` also have `nested` `replies`. I need to fetch all `replies` as a separate `comment`. But all `nested` `comments` and `replies` have the same `classname`.

Example html that i want to scrape :

```
<div class='post'>
<p>bla bla.</p>
</div>

<div class='comment'>
 <p>Comment1 <p>
  <div class='comment'>
   <p>Answer 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='comment'>
 <p>Comment2 <p>
  <div class='comment'>
   <p>Answer 1</p>
    <div class='comment'>
     <p>Answer 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='comment'>
 <p>Comment3 <p>
  <div class='comment'>
   <p>Answer 1</p>
    <div class='comment'>
     <p>Answer 2</p>
      <div class='comment'>
        <p>Answer 3</p> 
         <div class='comment'>
           <p>Answer 4</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i split all `nested comments`  and `replies`  and save all of them as `comments`. When i do like :

```
comments = doc.css('.comment')
 comments.each do |comment|
...
```

I can't get replies in a comment as a separate record. According to the above example, my code gives me just `3 comments` including `replies`.

Answer (score 1):

You can search nested `p` tags like `css('.comment p')`

```
html = <<~HTML
<div class='post'>
<p>bla bla.</p>
</div>

<div class='comment'>
 <p>Comment1 <p>
  <div class='comment'>
   <p>Answer 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='comment'>
 <p>Comment2 <p>
  <div class='comment'>
   <p>Answer 1</p>
    <div class='comment'>
     <p>Answer 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='comment'>
 <p>Comment3 <p>
  <div class='comment'>
   <p>Answer 1</p>
    <div class='comment'>
     <p>Answer 2</p>
      <div class='comment'>
        <p>Answer 3</p>
         <div class='comment'>
           <p>Answer 4</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
HTML
```

Just parse this way

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
comments = doc.css('.comment p')
```

Using this code you will get empty tags `<p>\n  </p>`, you can delete them.

```
comments.css('p').each { |p| comments.delete(p) if p.content.strip.empty? }

puts comments.to_html
```

```html
 <!-- will print -->

<p>Comment1 </p>
<p>Answer 1</p><p>Comment2 </p>
<p>Answer 1</p><p>Answer 2</p><p>Comment3 </p>
<p>Answer 1</p><p>Answer 2</p><p>Answer 3</p><p>Answer 4</p>
```